# Autolayout confusion

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Here are my views with constraints.

[image]

The problem is in landscape mode. For example, the purple view's height is 58.33(portrait mode), but in landscape mode is 36.33. But on iPad or iPhone 12 pro max, these two are equal.

[image]

1. Why they are different if the constraints are the same?
2. How can I set them to be the same (purple view's height in landscape mode and in portrait mode)?

Comment: If you want a fixed height, the add a height constraint. The devices have different screen sizes so you will need to allow something else to change if you fix the height.

Comment: I don't need a fixed size. I need only one thing that the purple view's height in landscape mode will be equal to the purple view's height in portrait mode.

Comment: It's very simple. The height is derived from width and the width is derived from your left and right margin constraints. In portrait mode, the width is so small that you need two lines of text, thus the height is bigger.
The solution is simpler - make the width fixed. For example, you can set the width to be a portion of the screen width (there is no shame in setting that one constraint through code) and use horizontal centering instead of left and right margins.
Or, make sure that your text is short enough to fit one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that this storyboard was a **container view** in the "X" storyboard and the "X" storyboard had several constraints related to this storyboard. That was the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: choose a button and setup its "Content Compression Resistance Priority" to 1000 (Required)

*Btw. SceneView is changing during rotation as well. It looks you've got other constraints to satisfy with a higher priority taking into account both of these views don't have a fixed height and completely defined by its content (intrinsic) sizes are subjects for stretching and squeezing when necessary
And first two vertical constraints from a screen look a bit unclear*